# Filter not working until report is reloaded

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports with vb.net and have a completed report with parameter fields and filtering.

Everything works correctly when running the report in crystal reports itself, but when accessing this report through my vb.net application, filtering does nothing, even though you are prompted for the parameters.

This application uses dozens of reports, all of which work as expected except for this one.  Strangely, if I open one of these other reports, let it load, then re-open the report in question, filtering works as expected immediately.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please add some source code, otherwise it seems to be impossible to answer this question.

Comment: Not sure what code there is to show.  I haven't worked on any vb.net code for this, and what code there is has been working with all reports, (including this one,) up until yesterday with no change whatsoever for over a year.  The problem has to somehow be a part of the .rpt file itself.

Comment: Too many questions asking, but when we tried to resolved nobodies respond at all. This is a problem of reporting Portion.

Comment: Figured out the problem.  The filtering formula was only placed in the 'Record' part of the Section Expert.  The same formula needed to be copied into the 'Saved Data' part.  Apparently it used different formulas depending on if it was the first loaded report or not.